# Pull content from production to staging server

Tags: 8, workflows, staging

I have a setup that consists of a Drupal 8 instance on my `localhost`, a staging instance on a `develop` server and a productive version on a `production` server. Initially, I was co-designing the theme, the configuration and so on on my machine. But now, the site is live.

For configuration changes, I can update my local instance and export the configuration. Pushing this to my `develop` branch in my git repository automatically triggers a deployment on the `develop` server. Creating a new release triggers a deployment on the `production` server.

Now this situation: Content editors create new nodes on the instance on the `production` server. On some piece of the new content, they discover an issue and want a fix for that and maybe even want to review this fix on the `develop` instance.

I already have such a neat deployment for the configuration, so I really want to avoid copying databases around. For images, there's a module, that can replace local static files with links to the productive version. What would be the equivalent solution for the content in the database?

What might be a useful flow for the case that there's no better automation:

- I do a composer update on my local machine
- The content from develop gets pulled to my local instance
- I commit my changes and pull them to the `develop` instance
- The `develop` instance pulls content from the `productive` instance
- The `develop` instance reads my new configuration

It would be even better if there would be some API magic that enables my instances on `localhost` and `develop` to read the content directly (and cache it).

So, is there some API magic around? Or do I have to write scripts and everything to pull databases from server to server?

Additional requirement: I did most of the work so far and have all the administrative rights, but in the future, this should work for additional developers who should not need to login onto a server.

Comment: Code goes up, data goes down. You don't want a setup where other environments "touch" production in the way Stage File Proxy does. Copying the database down is fine, and Drush has a sql:sync command to make this easy. The UI in Acquia and Pantheon and probably others make this a simple drag and drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is particularly difficult to Migrate. It's not as clean as Configuration. Generally, what you are talking about is not done - as Kevin points out, content is created on prod, and databases are pulled from prod to any other environment that needs that content. That said you could set up a Migration strategy with the Migrate API that could be used to migrate content around between environments. You're mostly on your own with this though - I haven't seen any tutorials for your specific issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I guess, that is the answer for now. I have some ideas how to do this customly. I just didn't want to start coding this on my own if there's a chance, that I'm missing something. Thank you :)

Comment: I would definitely use the Migration API. It still needs maturing overall, but is better than starting with something custom.